# SublimeText2 and Django build

Tags: django, sublimetext2

Just started using st2, switching from Eclipse pydev.

In Eclipse, I imported my Django project and could hit "Run" from any file and use the django framework.
for instance if I wanted to test something about my model class:

## models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout, login as auth_login

if __name__ == "__main__":
    auth_login(username, password)
```

This would run and validate.

However, in sublime text, I can't get my python virtual_env to build the same way.
I keep getting the following error when I import anything django:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested settings CACHES, but settings are not configured.

One way to fix it is to ADD to EVERY FILE i want to test:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
```

I was wondering if there is an easier way to include this? My current build file is:

```
{
"working_dir":          "/home/username/virtualenvs/workspace/myproject",
"env" : { "PYTHONPATH" : "/home/username/virtualenvs/workspace/myproject"},
"cmd" : "/home/username/virtualenvs/workspace/bin/python2.7",
"selector" : "source.python"
}
```

I've been searching around for hours...any help is appreciated!

Comment: Here are a few questions that come to mind which may help people give you answers. In your first example, what do you mean by "validate"? Why are you trying to execute individual files (e.g. `models.py`)? Where is the error about "settings are not configured" coming from? What happens if you set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in `env` in your build file?